What are the eigen values of Fischer's equation?
What are the eigen values of Fischer's equation $u_t=u_{xx}+u(1-u)$? I am asking in the sense just like for heat equations we have eigen values $\lambda=n\cdot \pi/l$, so what will be the eigen values in this case?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

This is a non-linear PDE and the eigenfunction/eigenvalue approach is only really useful for linear PDEs (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102068/what-is-the-purpose-of-computing-the-eigenvalue-of-a-pde-problem).

I know but we can linearize this using jacobian.

Actually I have tried to convert fishers equation into a system of ode, and I have also found a way to linearize the system into another dynamical system.. So I want to compare that if there is any analogy between the eigen values of the system of ode and the linearised dynamical system.

The eigenvalues will be depending to your boundary conditions. If you consider the linearized equation (for $u$ is small), $u_t=u_{xx}+u$, using separation of variables ($u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$), we obtain $$ XT'=X''T+XT \Rightarrow \frac{XT'}{XT}=\frac{X''T}{XT}+\frac{XT}{XT} \Rightarrow \frac{T'}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}+{1}=\lambda.$$ Knowing the boundary conditions, the eigenvalues for the linearized PDE can be solved, since we simply have a second order ODE: $X''+(1-\lambda)X=0$.

Thankyou for this nice explanation. But what if u is not small? because in my case it's not small!

@Simranbedi, this linearization is only allowed for the $u^2$ term being small. Since for $u$ near 1 also implies nonlinear term to vanis, this is an appropriate approach for $u\sim 1$. And if $u$ also does not satisfy this condition, then it means that the linear approximation for your eigenvalues is not valid. Then you cannot use this approach, by which the eigenvalues of the heat equation are found.

Okay, Thank you so much!
